# Are 401k and IRA contributions reduced for new, part-year, US residents?

Tags: 401k, ira, dual-status

Suppose I move to the US partway through the year and start working.  I will file a dual-status tax return.  My employer offers a 401k plan and I want to contribute as much as I am permitted.  I understand the maximum employee contribution for 2021 is $19,500.

Despite not being a tax resident (or any other kind of resident) for the full year, am I allowed to contribute the full $19,500 if I want to?  Or does this get reduced based on how many days of the year I am a tax resident of the US?

Likewise for the $6,000 IRA limit?

Comment: Just because you move to the US in the middle of the year does not necessarily mean you are dual-status. For example, if you don't pass the Substantial Presence Test or the Green Card Test, you are a nonresident alien for the whole year, although you might be able to use the First-Year Choice to become dual-status.

Comment: You're right, of course, but let's say that I have enough presence to make that choice.  And as you allude to in your answer, I guess it doesn't really matter whether I'm a resident or not, as long as the employment income is US-sourced.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the contribution limits are the same. Both resident aliens and nonresident aliens have the same contribution limit for IRAs -- $6,000 or their taxable compensation, whichever is less (although for nonresident aliens they can only count the compensation that is effectively connected to the US). I think the same is true for 401(k) contributions.